# Regex : Don't match if other text is found before

Tags: python, regex, markdown

I'm trying to parse a markdown document with a regex to find if there is a title in the document (# title).
I've manage to achieve this with this regex `(?m)^#{1}(?!#) (.*)`, the problem is that I can also have code section in my markdown where I can encounter the # title format as a comment.

My idea was to try to find the # title, but if in lines before there is a ```language then don't match.

Here is a text example where I need to only match `# my title` and not the `# helloworld.py` below, especially if `# my title` is missing (which is what I need to find out) :

````
<!--
.. title: Structuring a Python application
.. medium: yes
.. devto: yes
-->

# my title

In this short article I will explain all the different ways of structuring a Python application, from a quick script to a more complex web application.

## Single python file containing all the code


```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# helloworld.py

test
````

Comment: is a title bound to be present? and if it is present, is it always the very first phrase followed by a `#`?

Comment: If you don't need possible titles after a code block, you could use `document.partition("\`\`\`")[0]` instead of the full document.

Comment: A title is not bound to be present, and it is not the first phrase if its present, but I found my answer down bellow ! @Chase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could get real messy with regex. But since it seems like you'll be using python anyway - this can be trivial.

````py
mkdwn = '''<!--
.. title: Structuring a Python application
.. medium: yes
.. devto: yes
-->

# my title

In this short article I will explain all the different ways of structuring a Python application, from a quick script to a more complex web application.

## Single python file containing all the code


```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# helloworld.py

test'''

'''Get the first occurrence of a substring that
you're 100% certain **will not be present** before the title 
but **will be present** in the document after the title (if the title exists)
'''
idx = mkdwn.index('```')

# Now, try to extract the title using regex, starting from the string start but ending at `idx`
title_match = re.search(r'^# (.+)', mkdwn[:idx],flags=re.M)
# Get the 1st group if a match was found, else empty string
title = title_match.group(1) if title_match else ''
print(title)
````

You can also reduce this

```py
title_match = re.search(r'^# (.+)', mkdwn[:idx],flags=re.M)
# Get the 1st group if a match was found, else empty string
title = title_match.group(1) if title_match else ''
```

into a one liner, if you're into that sort of thing-

```py
title = getattr(re.search(r'^# (.+)', mkdwn[:idx],flags=re.M), 'group', lambda _: '')(1)
```

`getattr` will return the attribute `group` if present (i.e when match was found) - otherwise it'll just return that dummy function(`lambda _: ''`) which takes a dummy argument and returns an empty string, to be assigned to `title`.

The returned function is then called with the argument `1`, which returns the 1st group if a match was found. If a match wasn't found, well the argument doesn't matter, it just returns an empty string.

### Output

> my title

Comment: Yes you are right that I should just divide the work, it works ! Just for your information I need to use this regex : `r"(?<!#)#{1} .+"` or it will also match h2 titles `## title h2`

Comment: @MathieuDugue nope, it shouldn't match `## title h2`, `r"(?<!#)#{1} .+"` seems overcomplicated, just a `^# ` will be enough to only choose hashes that are at the beginning of a line and are also followed by a space. aka single hashes. Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/CYToBh/1)

Comment: My bad you are right ! I added a test to check if there was a `idx` because I could have a document without any code blocks, and in this case in searching the regex in the entire document. Works like a charm thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This is a task for three regular expressions. Screen all code fragments temporarily with the first one, process markdown with the second one, unscreen code with the third.

"Screening" means storing code fragments in a dictionary and replacing with some special markdown with dictionary key.